# find the "rebase -m" starting point

Tags: git, merge, rebase, cherry-pick

Recently I am using

```
git checkout dev_branch -b merge_branch
git rebase -m merge_branch master
git checkout master
git rebase merge_branch
```

to do a merge rebase. As the help document indicates, merge_branch is first reset to HEAD of master and then the new commits in original dev_branch is played back one by one to the new branch.

Several days later I want to find where is the "starting point" of this rebase merge. I can find the first delta commit in dev_branch using

```
git merge-base master dev_branch // Get an SHA_root of the common ancestor
git log --reverse -1 <SHA_root>..dev_branch  // Get an SHA_delta of the first delta commit
```

But I don't find a way to locate where is the merged version of

```
git branch --contains <SHA_delta>
```

But find it is only in "dev_branch", not in "master_branch", though actually it has been merged.

In another word, the same commit with different parent (like the situation using cherry-pick) are with different SHA. Is there a way that git can recognize them as actually identical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what [`git cherry`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry) does.

> In a situation where `topic` consisted of three commits, and the maintainer applied two of them, the situation might look like:
>
> ```
> $ git log --graph --oneline --decorate --boundary origin/master...topic
> * 7654321 (origin/master) upstream tip commit
> [... snip some other commits ...]
> * cccc111 cherry-pick of C
> * aaaa111 cherry-pick of A
> ```
>
> [… snip a lot more that has happened …]
>
> ```
> | * cccc000 (topic) commit C
> | * bbbb000 commit B
> | * aaaa000 commit A
> |/
> * 1234567 branch point
> ```
>
> In such cases, `git cherry` shows a concise summary of what has yet to be applied:
>
> ```
> $ git cherry origin/master topic
> - cccc000... commit C
> + bbbb000... commit B
> - aaaa000... commit A
> ```
>
> Here, we see that the commits A and C (marked with `-`) can be dropped from your `topic` branch when you rebase it on top of `origin/master`, while the commit B (marked with `+`) still needs to be kept so that it will be sent to be applied to `origin/master`.

Comment: Greg, thank you for introducing this useful command. But looks like it don't handle cases where the merge is involving some manual change (for conflict resolving) or situation that file are deleted.